# Displaying an PHP Array in a readable format

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

I'm a newbie when it comes to PHP, so I'm sorry if this is too simple and obvious.

I have a webform that users can add input fields to dynamically. When the user clicks submit all the input fields are saved into an array. When I use the print_r command I get an array that looks like this:

```
Array 
    ( 
    [1] => Array ( [tc] => 00:10 [feedback] => good ) 
    [2] => Array ( [tc] => 00:20 [feedback] => bad ) 
    [3] => Array ( [tc] => 00:21 [feedback] => Bigger text ) 
    )
```

The code I use to pull the data into the array is:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) { //The values have been posted
    $elements = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) { //For every posted values
        $frags = explode("_", $key); //we separate the attribute name from the number
        $id = $frags[1]; //That is the id
        $attr = $frags[0]; //And that is the attribute name
        if (!empty($val)) {
            //We then store the value of this attribute for this element.
            $elements[$id][$attr] = htmlentities($val);
        }
    }
}
```

The way I would like to display the data is like this:

```
01: 00:10 - good<br />
02: 00:20 - bad<br />
03: 00:21 - Bigger text<br />
```

The form I am trying to make can be found at http://ridefreemedia.com.au/test

Comment: It looks like you can avoid the work in building the multi-dimensional array from POST by simply specifying a multi-dimansion array in teh input fields like `<input name="id[]" ... />` rather than `<input name="id_key" ... />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate on the array, as such:

```
$arr = Array( 
    1 => Array ( "tc" => "00:10", "feedback" => "good" ),
    2 => Array ( "tc" => "00:20", "feedback"=> "bad" ),
    3 => Array ( "tc" => "00:21", "feedback" => "Bigger text" ) 
  );

foreach ($arr as $k => $info) {
  echo $k . ': ' . $info['tc'] . ' - ' . $info['feedback'] . '<br />'; 
}
```

Here the output will be:

> 1: 00:10 - good
>   2: 00:20 - bad
>   3: 00:21 - Bigger text

2 notables things, as I believe you're discovering `PHP`:

- `.` concatenates strings
- `foreach ($array as $k => $v)` iterates over the array.
  For each line, it puts the key of the line in `$k`, and the value in `$v`. Here, `$k = 1` and `$info = Array ( "tc" => "00:10", "feedback" => "good" )` on the first iteration.

Comment: Fantastic :) Thats exactly what I've been looking for. Yeah I'm completely new to PHP, so still trying to learn the basics.

Any ideas about where I would look if I want to send this to an email address? As in: The user fills out the form, clicks submit, the data is displayed to the user to confirm the data, then the user can click submit again to email the data to my email address..

Comment: You need to have a look at php's documentation: http://php.net/manual/function.mail.php
You'll find a lot of answers to your question there. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the array like this `$array_name[1]`.  Or, if the array value has a key, `$array_name['key_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're after, but `<pre>` would prettify it a bit.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($val);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

print_r won't do, as you can see it outputs the meta data of the array. try adding the field to a string and use echo to output the strings into the html code.